# Вставка вложенных данных в несколько таблиц. Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

### Что имеем:

- Модель `Product`
- Модель `User`

**Присутствуют разные связи между таблицами:**

- `Product` может содержать список основных `Users`
- `Product` может содержать список резервных `Users`
- `Product` содержит одного `Creator`, который также лежит в `Users`
- `User` может содержать список основных `Products`
- `User` может содержать список резервных `Products`

**Модели:**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductsAsCreator { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductsAsMain { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductsAsReserve { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatorId")]
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
    public int? CreatorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersAsMain { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> UsersAsReserve { get; set; }
}
```

### Что требуется:

- Обновлять / добавлять `Products`, которые могут содержать в себе как новых `Users`, так и существующих, с изменениями или без, которых также нужно обновлять / добавлять.

Сейчас пытаюсь сначала добавить всех пользователей, затем продукты:

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
{
    foreach (var product in Products)
    {
        if (product.Creator != null)
        {
            db.Users.AddOrUpdate(product.Creator);
        }

        db.Users.AddRange(product.UsersAsMain);
        db.Users.AddRange(product.UsersAsReserve);
    }

    db.Products.AddRange(Products);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Очевидно делаю не верно, при `SaveChanges` выкидывает исключение:

> constraint failed UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.Id

Это возможно из за того, что:

- `db.Users.AddRange(product.UsersAsMain);` может содержать `Creator`, который был добавлен ранее, а теперь идет повторная попытка
- `db.Products.AddRange(Products);` содержит всех пользователей, которых только что добавили, и также идет повторная попытка добавления

### Вопросы:

- Самый главный - как построить логику обновления / добавления всего этого?
- Можно ли обойтись без дополнительных переборов вложенных элементов с применением `AddOrUpdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставьте только

```
db.Products.AddRange(Products);
db.SaveChanges();
```

`Entity Framework` сам добавит `Users`

Comment: Пробовал сначала так. Если попадаются одинаковые пользователи, выкидывает указанное в вопросе исключение. Приходится проходиться по вложенным элементам и обнулять повторяющиеся.

Comment: @Skrim Скорее всего у вас одинаковые пользователи представлены разными объектами. Если бы вы использовали ссылку на уже существующего пользователя, а не создавали бы нового, то думаю, все бы работало.

Comment: @Skrim было бы интересно посмотреть, как вы создаете и наполняете объекты

Comment: Спасибо, действительно - каждый раз инициализирую пользователей, вместо установки ссылки на существующего. Но не инициализировать не могу, т.к. за это отвечает отдельный модуль, который не знает о существовании других `Product` и `User`. Остается понять как переустановить ссылки на один объект для повторяющихся пользователей. Но это уже другой вопрос.

Comment: Ruslan, `AddRange` по умолчанию устанавливает всем сущностям статус `EntityState.Added`? Если в бд уже лежат записи, то ругается на повторное добавление. Получается нужно подтягивать с бд и вручную менять на `EntityState.Modified`?

Comment: @Skrim Да, он проставляет всем `Added` по умолчанию. Посмотрите [рекомендуемый паттерн](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_5) для вашего случаю