# Переназначить ссылки повторяющихся объектов

Tags: c#, linq

Есть коллекция объектов `Product`, каждый из которых содержит две коллекции объектов `User` и одного главного пользователя `Creator`:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public User Creator { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> UsersAsMain { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> UsersAsReserve { get; set; }
}
```

- Объекты пользователей в обоих списках одного объекта `Product` все разные, не повторяются
- Копия (отдельный экземпляр) объекта `Creator` может находиться в одном из списков
- Объекты пользователей, находящиеся в одном `Product`, могут также быть и в остальных.

Нужно пройтись по всем пользователям и, если найдена его копия, присвоить ей ссылку на основной объект. В результате все одинаковые пользователи должны ссылаться на один объект в памяти.

Как составить LINQ запрос (возможно несколько), чтобы проверить и переопределить ссылки? Сравнивать достаточно по `Id`.

Comment: "Копия (отдельный экземпляр) объекта `Creator`" это вы создаете отдельно клон `User` и пихаете его в `Creator`? Или я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq

Comment: @Sublihim, верно, `Creator` может также присутствовать в одном из списков.

Comment: а зачем вы создаете копии объектов?

Comment: просто, я надеюсь, вы же понимаете, если вы сделали один раз `var user = new User(...)` и потом этот user вставляете и в списки и в Creator, то там и будут хранится лишь ссылки на один единственный объект в памяти?

Comment: @Sublihim, есть модуль, который получает данные с сайта. Он возвращает по одному `Product`, который содержит пользователей. О том какие данные уже получены он не знает, поэтому каждый раз инициализирует всех пользователей. В итоге получается набор повторяющихся данных, лежащих отдельно.

Comment: @Sublihim, да, каждый пользователь также инициализируется в отдельном методе, который не знает о существующих пользователях. Поэтому `Creator` лежит в памяти отдельно.

Comment: Так это, наверно и надо указывать в вопросе, иначе совершенно непонятно. Это раз. Во-вторых, вы хотите напрямую управлять памятью в C# это же вам не C++

Comment: Т.е. в вашем случае будет проще, ИМХО, просто пересоздать уже все заново и продукты и юзеров. Имея набор данных, а то, что приходит с сервера, пусть умирает в GC

Comment: @Skrim [premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). Текущая ситуация вызывает проблемы с производительностью? Если нет, то пусть это будет проблема GC, а не ваша.

Comment: @VladislavKhapin вопрос является следствием [этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/607566/195080) вопроса. Там проблема с Entity Framework

Comment: @VladislavKhapin, это нужно, чтобы выполнить запись в бд через `AddRange` Entity Framework'a, иначе запись идет очень медленно.

Comment: @Skrim самое простое - написать свою логику обработки и вставки, возможно даже на чистом ADO .NET. Ну можно, конечно, использовать кеш и написать логику замены на объекты из него же, но это дикий костыль над EF как мне кажется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем объект, который хранит ссылки на пользователей

```
Dictionary<int, User> users = new Dictionary<int, User>();
```

Проходим по всем коллекциям, берем User, ищем в `users`, если нашли - подменяем ссылкой, если нет - добавляем в `users`

```
foreach (Product product in products)
{
    foreach (User user in product.UsersAsMain.ToArray())
    {
        if (users.ContainsKey(user.Id))
        {
            product.UsersAsMain.Remove(user);
            product.UsersAsMain.Add(users[user.Id]);
        }
        else
        {
            users.Add(user.Id, user);
        }
    }
    foreach (User user in product.UsersAsReserve.ToArray())
    {
        if (users.ContainsKey(user.Id))
        {
            product.UsersAsReserve.Remove(user);
            product.UsersAsReserve.Add(users[user.Id]);
        }
        else
        {
            users.Add(user.Id, user);
        }
    }
    if (users.ContainsKey(product.Creator.Id))
    {
        product.Creator = users[product.Creator.Id];
    }
    else
    {
        users.Add(product.Creator.Id, product.Creator);
    }
}
```

Конечно, это большой костыль. Вам бы разобрать как в этих коллекциях оказались клоны.